# Using PHP to send photo URLs to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am helping my friend with his photo website oneonethousand.org. He wants the photo gallery to be generated automatically from the photos he places in a directory. I am not experienced with Ajax and think it might be too complex to use for this.

What I think would be best is to use PHP to identify the URLs of the photos in a directory and somehow send those URLs to JavaScript so that JavaScript can pre-load them and then display them when the corresponding photo button is selected on the site.

I know PHP and JavaScript (JQuery) relatively well, but I'm just not quite sure what the Best Practice is for what I need to do.

Just to reiterate: What he wants to do is place the photos in the directory, PHP searches that directory for the photo names, and passes those URLs to JavaScript so it can pre-load them.

How do you recommend going about this?

Comment: You can see an example gallery here http://oneonethousand.org/photographers/traviesa/

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. Are you asking if it's a good idea to do such a thing? I'd say it's a valid approach the only problem is that you probably don't want to load all the images in a directory simultaneously; you'll likely want to generate thumbnails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use AJAX to do this, but you certainly don't have to. In your page that is loaded by the browser, you can make PHP print Javascript, like so:

```
$HTML  = '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
$HTML .= 'var ImageCache = [];'            . "\n";

foreach (glob('Path/To/Images/*.jpg') as $Image))
{
    $HTML .= 'ImageCache.push("' . $Image . '");' . "\n";
}

$HTML .= 'for (var i in ImageCache) {'                 . "\n";
$HTML .= "\t" . 'var Source = ImageCache[i]; '         . "\n";
$HTML .= "\t" . 'ImageCache[i] = new Image(100, 100);' . "\n";
$HTML .= "\t" . 'ImageCache[i].src = Source;'          . "\n";
$HTML .= '}';

$HTML .= '</script>';
```

Comment: Okay. Teaching moment - I'm not really clear on what "$HTML .= " does... is $HTML just a normal variable or is that like using echo? Forgive me... my PHP knowledge is limited... I generally just use echo and do simple things.

Comment: OH... ".=" is adding that code to the variable and then I would do "echo $HTML" right?

Comment: The .= means concatenation. $HTML .= 'a'; is the same thing as $HTML = $HTML . 'a'; It will add 'a' to the end of the existing $HTML string.

Comment: How would I do this with Ajax?

Comment: First off, I would recommend the use of a Javascript library such as JQuery to do the AJAX call for you. When the page loads, you'd initiate the AJAX call. The PHP script that gets invoked would do the globbing and return a list of strings to you. The Javascript that handles the response would then do the same thing as the original post-- create an array of Image objects and set their sources.

Comment: It's the request part of Ajax I am unclear about, because this is never explained. Is the request like "run somefile.php"? And then that php returns a value? See, I mostly do java programming for research, so this www world with requests and such is new to me.

Comment: Ben, sorry it took me so long to see your reply. When you request a page in your browser, you contact a remote server that assembles the page and sends you HTML. In AJAX, you run code on the user's computer that asynchronously requests a web page from the remote server. You can return data back in a variety of types. The most common, however, are JSON, XML, and HTML. If you're still in need of resources, take a look at the JQuery AJAX docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You'd generally use a function like [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get a list of all of the image files, then embed links to them in the page either directly, or using javascript as you suggested.

Something like this ...

```
$files = glob("/image/dir/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

$js = "var images = new Array();\n";

foreach( $files as $i => $file ) {
    $fileName = basename($file);
    $js .= "images[$i] = '$fileName';\n";
}
```

Adding the $js as Javascript to your page will get you a list of the image names, client-side, which you can use as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

To transer data from PHP to javascript you can use XMLor JSON.
PHP provides functions and classes for both.

Using JSON is very simple

For more details about PHP and JSON see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

For information about decoding the data in JavaScript read this http://json.org/js.html

EDIT:
If you generate your javascript in php you can encode a an array in JSON and use the generated code to declare a JavaScript array.

```
echo <<<END
<script>
...
var images = {$JSONEncodedArray};
...
</script
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dynamically generate a part of your JavaScript file with PHP, like so:

```
var slideshowImages = [<?php
$files_in_folder = /* get the files somehow */;
foreach($files_in_folder as $file) {
     echo "\"$file\",";
}
?>null]; // Make sure to skip the last element
```

You might need to give your .js file a .php extension, if it is in fact a separate file.

Comment: I didn't know I could do php inside of javascript!  Whats the " [ " for?

Comment: `[]` is literal syntax for arrays. So `["one", "two"]` is equivalent to `new Array("one", "two")`.